# .htaccess redirect email address to URL parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm currently trying to convert an email address sent in a URL into a parameter which can be passed into a PHP script. The URL is 
`http://example.com/email@example.com`, and I need it to be passed as a parameter for example `http://example.com/?email=email@example.com`

Currently testing on Apache with PHP 7.2, both locally on my machine and also on a shared hosting platform.

Tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?<!results=).*@.*)$ ?email=%1 [L]
```

And this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$
RewriteRule /(.*)$ index.php?email=$1 [L]
```

Both of these just return a 404 Not Found error, and do not seem to be redirecting at all.

Comment: Well, what resource is `/` meant to point at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague, since it is not really clear what resource is meant to process those requests in the end...

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^@]+@[a-z0-9_-]+\.\w+)$ /index.php?email=$1 [END,NC]
```

This assumes that you have a script `index.php` in your http host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder which processes such requests.

For this to work you need to make sure that the apache rewriting module is actually loaded into the http server and has been enabled and configured for that location.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).